# What does it mean by DiskCookies Crash on iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I use Fabric to log crash on my iOS App. 
Today, I came across some crash related to DiskCookies. I really don't know what it means.

```
Crashed: diskcookies
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1bd00136 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 53
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b5d9cf3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 3240
2  CFNetwork                      0x1c44a359 DiskCookieStorage::writeFileCompletely0(DiskCookieStorage*, FilePathStat*, MemoryCookies const*, __CFData const*, TracerData*, int) + 634
3  CFNetwork                      0x1c44a49d DiskCookieStorage::_asyncWriteFileCompletely(void*) + 174
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b4a1783 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b4ada35 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 50
6  CFNetwork                      0x1c44b09d DiskCookieStorage::syncStorageWithCompletionLocked(unsigned char, void () block_pointer) + 2220
7  CFNetwork                      0x1c44277b ___CFHTTPCookieStorageFlushCookieStores_block_invoke + 86
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1bcf5447 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 20
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1bce0634 CFBasicHashApply + 120
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1bce94c1 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 152
11 CFNetwork                      0x1c44270f _CFHTTPCookieStorageFlushCookieStores + 140
12 libsystem_c.dylib              0x1b53720d __cxa_finalize_ranges + 290
13 libsystem_c.dylib              0x1b4f61b3 exit + 12
14 Comico                         0x97a74f UnityGetGLViewController + 4756906
15 Comico                         0x97a265 UnityGetGLViewController + 4755648
16 Comico                         0x980a6b UnityGetGLViewController + 4782278
17 Comico                         0x96dfb5 UnityGetGLViewController + 4705808
18 Comico                         0x96da59 UnityGetGLViewController + 4704436
19 Comico                         0x200fe3 -[AppDelegate setUpAppGuardWithUserID:] (AppDelegate.m:1303)
20 Comico                         0x1ff967 __36-[AppDelegate dologinInCallLoginAPI]_block_invoke (AppDelegate.m:1026)
21 Comico                         0x13f69b __42-[NCLoginRAPIManager loginWithCompletion:]_block_invoke (NCLoginRAPIManager.m:97)
22 Comico                         0xde19f -[NCRAPICompletion performBlockWithOperation:] (NCRAPICompletion.m:94)
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1bd06323 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 218
24 Comico                         0x3adf0d -[NCRAPIOperationRegister performCompletionBlockOfOperation:] (NCRAPIOperationRegister.m:67)
25 Comico                         0x251ce1 __51-[NCRAPIManager callRAPIWithAPIRequest:completion:]_block_invoke_2 (NCRAPIManager.m:65)
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b4a1797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b4a1783 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b4a5d05 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 902
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1bd8fd69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1bd8de19 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1bce11af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1bce0fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
33 GraphicsServices               0x1d48bb41 GSEventRunModal + 80
34 UIKit                          0x21069a53 UIApplicationMain + 150
35 Comico                         0x20dc39 main (main.m:19)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b4ce4eb start + 2
```

I believe someone is trying to modify the path where network library put data to. Does anyone have any other theory or have some experience on this crash?

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace you posted here is my theory.

- Frame 14 indicates that you've got a Unity application, and it's doing its thing running OpenGL.
- Frame 13 is really interesting. It seems like the Unity `UnityGetGLViewController` (which I assume is not written by you) has called `exit`. This is surprising behavior, but it gives lots of clues on the rest of the stack.
- Frames 12-2 look like the network stack is just doing some work on application exit (triggered by `UnityGetGLViewController`). Seems like it is just writing some cookie-related stuff to disk. I wouldn't worry about this.
- Frame 0 and 1 are really suspect. I have a very hard time believing that malloc calls into CoreFoundation. If I had to guess, I would say that frame 0 is correct, and frame 1 has been mis-symbolicated or incorrectly unwound.

It's very unusual to call `exit` in iOS applications. While it is technically API, I doubt it is heavily tested. My bet is that there are some dangling pointer and/or object lifecycle issues related to the use of `exit` and you are seeing it here.

What I would do is see if Unity has any documentation around `UnityGetGLViewController` calling `exit`. I'd also check in with the Fabric people about frames 1 and 0. I don't see how both could be correct. And, finally, I might consider opening a bug with Apple. However, Apple usually doesn't like looking at non-Apple crash reports. So, that last one is probably a long-shot.